# Wiley documentclass and the min-function

Tags: amsmath

I am preparing a paper based on the Wiley template. It does not seem to recognize the min-function (nor the max-function):

```
\documentclass[AMA,final]{WileyNJD-v1}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
%\DeclareMathOperator{min}{min}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\min_{x}(a,b)
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

The compiler reports:

```
l.6 \min
        _{x}(a,b)
? H
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

I tried to add the commented lines but they did not help.

Comment: Typo. Did you mean `\DeclareMathOperator{\min}{min}`?

Comment: The amsmath package  defines `\min` and `equation*` your example then works with `article` (I do not have the wiley class to test)

Comment: Yes, I meant {\min}{min}. And yes, it works with the article class but not with the Wiley class.

Comment: Just noticed your comment on -v2. It seems to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I didn't have the class, but -v2 is available at several places including overleaf, with -v2 using `amsmath` works as expected

```
\documentclass[AMA,final]{WileyNJD-v2}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\min_{x}(a,b)
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]